# In Android 10, the file path from an image URI is not truly retrieved

Tags: android, scoped-storage

In an Android application,
I can get path of an Image from its URI
Now in ***Android 10***, null is returned as file path

Below you can see the functions:

```
    public static String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri, String type) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            String path = null;
            try {
                String[] projection = {type};
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
                if (cursor == null)
                    return null;
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(type);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                path = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                // we choose image from drive etc.
                if (path == null)
                    path = getDocumentRealPathFromUri(context, contentUri);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
            return path;
        }
     public static String getFullSizeImagePath(Context context, Uri uri)
        {
            String filePath;
            if (validateUri(uri) && uri.toString().contains("file"))
                filePath = uri.getPath();
            else
                filePath = getRealPathFromURI(context, uri, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (filePath == null)
                return null;
    
            return filePath;
        }
```

What is the problem?

**Edit 1:**
Then I use the following code:

```
    public static String resizeAndCompressImageBeforeSend(Context context,String filePath,String fileName){
            final int MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 700 * 1024; // max final file size in kilobytes
    
            // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions of image
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
    
            // Calculate inSampleSize(First we are going to resize the image to 800x800 image, in order to not have a big but very low quality image.
            //resizing the image will already reduce the file size, but after resizing we will check the file size and start to compress image
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 800, 800);
    
            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            options.inPreferredConfig= Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    
            Bitmap bmpPic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
    
            //Log.e("ds", "dsadsadasda 222222 byteSizeOfBitmap(realImage) = "+byteSizeOfBitmap(bmpPic) );
    
    
            int compressQuality = 100; // quality decreasing by 5 every loop.
            int streamLength;
            do{
                ByteArrayOutputStream bmpStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Log.d("compressBitmap", "Quality: " + compressQuality);
                bmpPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpStream);
            byte[] bmpPicByteArray = bmpStream.toByteArray();
            streamLength = bmpPicByteArray.length;
            compressQuality -= 5;
            Log.d("compressBitmap", "Size: " + streamLength/1024+" kb");
        }while (streamLength >= MAX_IMAGE_SIZE);

        try {
            //save the resized and compressed file to disk cache
            Log.d("compressBitmap","cacheDir: "+context.getCacheDir());
            FileOutputStream bmpFile = new FileOutputStream(context.getCacheDir()+fileName);
            bmpPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpFile);
            bmpFile.flush();
            bmpFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("compressBitmap", "Error on saving file");
        }
        //return the path of resized and compressed file
        return  context.getCacheDir()+fileName;
    }
```

Which as the name of the function specifies, resizes And Compresses the Image Before Sending to server
That's why I need the file path

**Edit2:**
I add the error as following:

```
04-04 14:42:04.936 14793-14920/com.example.vh80705.myapplication6 W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider uri content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/storage/emulated/0/Download/MellatMobileBank_Android.apk/junit/runner/logo.gif from pid=14793, uid=10251 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:423)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:946)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:881)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:837)
        at com.example.vh80705.myapplication6.B1_GeneralClasses.A8_GetFilePathFromURI.GetFilePathFromURI.getRealPathFromURI(GetFilePathFromURI.java:193)
        at com.example.vh80705.myapplication6.B1_GeneralClasses.A8_GetFilePathFromURI.GetFilePathFromURI.getFullSizeImagePath(GetFilePathFromURI.java:241)
04-04 14:42:04.937 14793-14920/com.example.vh80705.myapplication6 W/System.err:     at com.example.vh80705.myapplication6.B13_Network.HandleActionList.MultipleCommands.GetImageURIStringPath.GetImageURIStringPath_M2_Class.GetImageURIString_M2(GetImageURIStringPath_M2_Class.java:41)
        at com.example.vh80705.myapplication6.B13_Network.HandleActionList.MultipleCommands.SendCommand_MultipleCommandsFromActionList.Handle_UploadImageCommand(SendCommand_MultipleCommandsFromActionList.java:823)
        at com.example.vh80705.myapplication6.B13_Network.HandleActionList.MultipleCommands.SendCommand_MultipleCommandsFromActionList.access$100(SendCommand_MultipleCommandsFromActionList.java:79)
        at com.example.vh80705.myapplication6.B13_Network.HandleActionList.MultipleCommands.SendCommand_MultipleCommandsFromActionList$1.doWork(SendCommand_MultipleCommandsFromActionList.java:208)
        at com.example.vh80705.myapplication6.B13_Network.HandleActionList.MultipleCommands.SendCommand_MultipleCommandsFromActionList$1.doWork(SendCommand_MultipleCommandsFromActionList.java:191)
        at needle.UiRelatedTask.run(UiRelatedTask.java:20)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

**Edit 3:**
The above permission denial is seen in the following line of code:

```
cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
```

**Edit 4:**
I tried to utilize openinputstream instead of utilizing filepath as suggested in the comments but again the same error is appeared as following:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.miui.gallery.provider.GalleryOpenProvider uri content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20210404-WA0000.jpg from pid=30633, uid=10251 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

In the line:

```
mInputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mURI);
```

The new code is as following:

```
 public static String resizeAndCompressImageBeforeSend_ScopedStorage(Context context, Uri mURI, String fileName){
        final int MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 700 * 1024; // max final file size in kilobytes

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions of image
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        //BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize(First we are going to resize the image to 800x800 image, in order to not have a big but very low quality image.
        //resizing the image will already reduce the file size, but after resizing we will check the file size and start to compress image
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 800, 800);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig= Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

        Log.e("ddsds", "qqqwwweeerrr 2.1:"+mURI);

        //////Bitmap bmpPic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath,options);
        InputStream mInputStream;
        try
        {
            mInputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mURI);
            Log.e("ddsds", "qqqwwweeerrr 2.2:"+mInputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ddsds", "qqqwwweeerrr 3.1111111111"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        Bitmap bmpPic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mInputStream,null,options);

        Log.e("ddsds", "qqqwwweeerrr 3.1");

        //Log.e("ds", "dsadsadasda 222222 byteSizeOfBitmap(realImage) = "+byteSizeOfBitmap(bmpPic) );


        int compressQuality = 100; // quality decreasing by 5 every loop.
        int streamLength;
        do{
            ByteArrayOutputStream bmpStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.d("compressBitmap", "Quality: " + compressQuality);
            bmpPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpStream);
            byte[] bmpPicByteArray = bmpStream.toByteArray();
            streamLength = bmpPicByteArray.length;
            compressQuality -= 5;
            Log.d("compressBitmap", "Size: " + streamLength/1024+" kb");
        }while (streamLength >= MAX_IMAGE_SIZE);

        try {
            //save the resized and compressed file to disk cache
            Log.d("compressBitmap","cacheDir: "+context.getCacheDir());
            FileOutputStream bmpFile = new FileOutputStream(context.getCacheDir()+fileName);
            bmpPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpFile);
            bmpFile.flush();
            bmpFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("compressBitmap", "Error on saving file");
        }
        //return the path of resized and compressed file
        Log.e("ddsds", "qqqwwweeerrr 6.1"+context.getCacheDir()+fileName);
        return  context.getCacheDir()+fileName;
    }
```

Comment: You can read the image from the uri. Why do you need file path?

Comment: I use a function which I added above as Edit and there I need the image path

Comment: "I can get path of an Image from its URI" -- not usually. "That's why I need the file path" -- there is nothing in that function that requires a filesystem path to the image. `BitmapFactory` has `decodeStream()`, and you can get a stream on the content via `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: I recommend reading a whole [series of blog posts](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html) on Storage Access Framework written by CommonsWare (hello there) to get the full picture. But in short, you let the user *import* an image to your app (read from uri), process it, and then let the user *export* the image (write to another uri). You don't work with ordinary files across apps anymore.

Comment: Please see the Edit 4 above